# WPF Label binding via Tag to multiple ComboBoxes

Tags: wpf, xaml, label

Normally I associate Labels with TextBoxes/ComboBoxes on a one-to-one basis so I can decorate the label when the ComboBox has focus ... something like this

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Style="{StaticResource styleLabelTextBlockLeft}"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=cboColor, Path=(IsFocused)}"
>
    <TextBlock
        TextWrapping="Wrap">What is your favorite color? 
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cboColor"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="3"
    ...
/>
```

What I would like to do is highlight the Label if *either* the ComboBox to the immediate right of the Label has focus OR the second ComboBox to the right of the first ComboBox has focus (all on the same row).  Pseudocode follows:

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Style="{StaticResource styleLabelTextBlockLeft}"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=cboColorOne, Path=(IsFocused)}"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=cboColorTwo, Path=(IsFocused)}"
>
    <TextBlock
        TextWrapping="Wrap">What is your favorite color? 
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cboColorOne"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="3"
    ...
/>
<ComboBox
    x:Name="cboColorTwo"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="5"
    ...
/>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't even realize WPF still had the `Tag` property on controls...

Answer (score 2):

If you want a pure xaml solution you can use style datatriggers.
default the tag to false in the style
then write a trigger for each combobox that when focused set the tag to true.

```
<Label.Style>
   <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleLabelTextBlockLeft}">
     <Setter Property="Tag" Value="False" />
     <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cboColor, Path=(IsFocused)}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Tag" Value="True" />
       </DataTrigger>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cboColor2, Path=(IsFocused)}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Tag" Value="True" />
       </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class with a property that implements the needed logic, then bind the DataContext of a Control that contains the Label in question to this Class. Next you bind the tag of this Label to the class's property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MultiBinding/MultiValueConverter.  Just derive a class from IMultiValeConverter as follows:

```
public class ComboBoxFocusedConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)values[0] || (bool)values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[0]
    }
}
```

Then reference it in your resources:

```
<....Resources>
    <yournamespace:ComboBoxFocusedConverter x:Key="ComboBoxFocusedConverter" />
</....Resources>
```

And use it like so:

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="1"
     Grid.Column="1"
    Style="{StaticResource styleLabelTextBlockLeft}"
>
    <Label.Tag>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusedConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="cboColorOne" Path="IsFocused" />
            <Binding ElementName="cboColorTwo" Path="IsFocused" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Tag>
    <TextBlock
        TextWrapping="Wrap">What is your favorite color? 
    </TextBlock>
</Label>
```